# Generate lots of fake integers ( scores 1-5 ) without averaging out

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, seed

I'm writing an e-commerce website for school and i want to populate it with a couple thousand reviews, reclamations, orders, users, etc.

Reviews of a product include an integer score (1-5), and the product page displays an average score for each products

In my Review factory for the seeder i just have

```
  public function definition()
  {
    return[
      'user_id' => User::all()->random()->id,
      'book_id' => Book::all()->random()->id,
      'text' => fake()->paragraph,
      'score' => rand(1,5),
    ];
  }
```

This works fine except that, since i'm generating over 10k reviews, all my products average out to  an average score of 3 ( Average score works fine, it's not a bug ).

**Question**: How would i go about generating random scores that wouldn't average out ?

Comment: Any set of scores will average to something. Can you be more specific about what "average out" means?

Comment: so you are always getting an AVG=3 ? Where are you performing the calculation ? you are expecting to get AVG different than 3 correct ?

Comment: @jvmcollaborator That's exactly right. Each one of my products ends up with average score of 3. In very rare cases 2. 
The calculation is done by an observer that calculates the average score whenever a review is added to a book.
Manually adding reviews gives correct average scores, and smaller fake data sets are fine, only when generating loads of them do i encounter the issue of everything being AVG=3

Comment: Before commit and Created method ?

Comment: after commit, created method

Comment: Before commit gives the same results ?

Comment: Yes, but before commit ignores the latest commit when testing manually.

Comment: interesting doing some tests on my end. what kills me is the fact that works with a small amount of objects from the factory

Comment: If you generate numbers from 0 to 5 randomly then on the large set it is expected that they are evenly distributed and therefore the average will be three. There is no escaping that.

Comment: Small amount works fine since there's not enough entries for it to average out. at 300 reviews for 100 products there's not enough for the average to settle at 3. 
At 30 000 reviews for 100 products math takes over and AVG = 3, last answer solved my problem. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @DavidBrossard that's exactly what i described, and escaping that was my question. The accepted answer fixed my issue. Thanks for your time

Comment: im going to add this to laravel github as an issue, do you agree ? thanks for your time too

Comment: yes, for sure. @jmvcollaborator EDIT: It's not a laravel issue thou, it's just math and i couldn't figure out a workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use some property of the book to generate different score ranges.

Here's an example with the book ID:

```php
public function definition()
{
    $book = Book::all()->random();

    if ($book->id % 2 === 1) {
        $score = random_int(3, 5); // better score
    } else {
        $score = random_int(1, 3); // worse score
    }

    return[
        'user_id' => User::all()->random()->id,
        'book_id' => $book->id,
        'text' => fake()->paragraph,
        'score' => $score,
    ];
}
```

Assuming the book ID is an integer sequence, half the books should have a "bad to medium" score and the rest will have "medium to good". You can increase the modulus to program in more cases.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your desired outcome of the factory would be more life-like. I can imagine that a book store would mostly sell books rated 4 and higher.

So in essence, you'd want your factory to take this into account. Meaning that when a Book is generated by a factory it has a high probability of getting a score of 4 or 5.

There are many ways to accomplish this, one simple solution would be to do something like this:

```php
  public function definition()
  {
    return[
      'user_id' => User::all()->random()->id,
      'book_id' => Book::all()->random()->id,
      'text' => fake()->paragraph,
      'score' => $this->getBookScore(),
    ];
  }

  public static getBookScore(): int
  {
     // In 80% of the cases return a value of 4 or 5
     if(rand(0,100) < 80){
       return rand(4,5);
     }
     // Otherwise, something between 1 and 5.
     return rand(1,5);
  }
```